# Focussing a WebView after a MessageDialog is closed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, webview, windows-store-apps

I've got a `contentEditable` based editor within a `WebView` in my Windows Store app. Certain keyboard shortcuts and buttons can cause a `MessageDialog` to open. When this dialog is dismissed, the editor no longer has focus. I've tried setting focus every way I know, and it won't work. Here's a sample app.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="Editor" Margin="200"></WebView>
    </Grid>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar x:Name="CommandBar_Editor" Visibility="Visible">
            <AppBarButton Label="Debug" Icon="Setting">
                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="show dialog, then focus" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click_1"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        Editor.NavigateToString("<script type='text/javascript'>function focus_please(){ document.getElementById('editor').focus(); }</script><div id='editor' contentEditable='true'>It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</div>");
    }

    private async void MenuFlyoutItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("this should set focus to editor on close", "test");
        UICommand okCommand = new UICommand("OK");
        dialog.Commands.Add(okCommand);

        IUICommand response = await dialog.ShowAsync();

        if (response == okCommand)
        {
            Editor.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
            // I've also tried:
            // FocusState.Keyboard
            // FocusState.Pointer 
            // FocusState.Unfocused

            // this calls JS within the HTML to focus the contentEditable div
            await Editor.InvokeScriptAsync("focus_please", null);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the `WebView` is focussed, but not the HTML content within

## Update:

Updated my example to add in Bryan's code from the answer below, but it's still not working.

**Note** After the MessageDialog is dismissed, if I press `Tab` twice the editor becomes active again.

## Update 2:

Bryan's answer below *does* work when using the touch screen to navigate. However when using mouse and keyboard, the `contentEditable` element does not focus. I've put a bounty on this looking for a solution which allows the item to be focussed either when using the touch screen or the mouse / keyboard combo

Answer (score 4):

If you set focus state in C# the correct parameter is always FocusState.Programmatic. The other values are there for the purpose of reading the current focus value.

Sounds like you are trying to focus the control *within the webview* instead of the actual webview. The C#/XAML side of things will not know about the content within the webview. For that you will have to invoke javascript which will know about the controls.

Here is a link to MSDN on your scenerio. [WebView.Focus method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.focus)

Edit: According to the article, the WebView must get focus first, then the javascript invoked.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string html = "<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>function focusContent()" +
                      " {if(window.location.hash != '#TaleofTwoCities'){ window.location.hash = '#TaleofTwoCities';}};" +
                      "</script></head><body><div id='TaleofTwoCities' contentEditable='true'>It was the best of times, it was the worst of times</div></body></html>";

        Editor.NavigateToString(html);
    }

    private async void MenuFlyoutItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("this should set focus to editor on close", "test");
        UICommand okCommand = new UICommand("OK");
        dialog.Commands.Add(okCommand);

        IUICommand response = await dialog.ShowAsync();

        if (response == okCommand)
        {
            await Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Editor.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
            });
            await Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Editor.InvokeScript("focusContent", null);
            });
        }
    }
```

Here's my XAML

```
<Page x:Class="StackOverflow.WebViewFocus"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:StackOverflow"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"><WebView Width="300"
             x:Name="Editor"
             Height="300"></WebView>
        <Button Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click_1">focus</Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="CommandBar_Editor"
                Visibility="Visible">
        <AppBarButton Label="Debug"
                      Icon="Setting">
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="show dialog, then focus"
                                    Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click_1" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

Comment: I've tried focussing the content within the webview and the webview itself, they work neither separately nor together

Comment: I've tried `document.getElementById('editor').focus()`, I've tried jquery's `$("#editor").focus()` and I've tried setting the window.location.hash as you did above. (Also, it's *A Tale of Two Cities!*)

Comment: Tale of Two Cities oh yeah, haha. Here is an updated version. I tried dispatching the calls individually. I guessed the dispatcher was scheduling the calls out of order, perhaps? Anyway, this "works on my machine."

Comment: nope, still not working. are you testing this as a wpf app or a windows store app?

Comment: Windows store app. I added a second button to the left which works fine. It doesn't work if I don't click anywhere in the app, and use touch input to open the app bar. SOMEHOW though it DOES work if the text has been focused before, or if I click somewhere on the screen and THEN try the app bar button.

Comment: Ah, ok. The original version works with the touch screen, but if I use mouse and keyboard I have to press tab to regain focus. Something odd is going on here